# How do I solve ClassCastException error?

Tags: java, android, string, classcastexception

I have an error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.sjdav.searchfilterlist,
>   PID: 6394
>                                                                                     java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   com.example.sjdav.searchfilterlist.StringObj
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.sjdav.searchfilterlist.ValueAdapter.getView(ValueAdapter.java:80)

Which is here in `ValueAdapter`:

```
public class ValueAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "ValueAdapter";

    private ArrayList<StringObj> mStringList;
    private ArrayList<StringObj> mStringFilterList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ValueFilter valueFilter;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;
    private int lastPosition = 1;

    public ValueAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<StringObj> stringObjs) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;
        this.mStringList = stringObjs;
        this.mStringFilterList = mStringList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        getFilter();
    }

    // How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mStringList.size();
    }

    //Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mStringList.get(position);
    }

    //Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class  Holder {
        TextView textView1;
        ImageView imageView1;
    }

    //Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data set.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Setup Image Loading
        setUpImageLoader();

        Log.i(TAG, "getView: VA >> Image Loader complete..");

<!-- HERE -->   String name = mStringList.get(position).getName();
                String imgURL = mStringList.get(position).getImgURL();
```

And the `StringObj` class:

```
public class StringObj {

    public String name;
    public String imgURL;

    public StringObj(String name, String imgURL) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imgURL = imgURL;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImgURL() {
        return imgURL;
    }

    public void setImgURL(String imgURL) {
        this.imgURL = imgURL;
    }
}
```

I would have thought that casting name variable as a `String` and getting a String from an `ArrayList` of `StringObj` (which have two strings in them) would have been fine? I obviously don't understand what is happening here, so could someone help please? Thanks!

Comment: Is your adapter class is a nested class in your `Activity` or `Fragment`? If yes, then is it having a variable named `mStringList`?

Comment: show the place where have you cast it ??

Comment: Looks like you managed to get some plain `String` into your list of `StringObj`. Did you do some unchecked casting somewhere?

Comment: @ReazMurshed ValueAdapter is the adapter class, Main class is calling adapter = ValueAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_view, stringObjArrayList). Passing an ArrayList<StringObj> as stringObjs which mStringList is set as.

Comment: @pskink Yes exactly, and I try to extract String by using .getName() method from StringObj class in ValueAdapter class. I tried using ArrayAdapter and couldn't get the filter to work so went to this.

Comment: yes, i missed `getName()`  so what is the line in ValueAdapter.java line number 80? post that line with that cast - i dont see any `(StringObj)` cast in your code

Comment: `String name = mStringList.get(position).getName();` @pskink, I think this is the line you are looking for.

Comment: no, there is no cast here, open `ValueAdapter.java` in your editor and go to line number 80, what is it?

Comment: Line 80 is String name = mStringList.get(position).getName(); where I have commented <!-- HERE -->

Comment: post your whole adapter then